Exposing Global Variable In Vite
After hours of searching through the doc (Vite) I've realised there is no simple way to expose a global string variable accessible via window.MY_VARIABLE in the browser console. At least as I can see the exposed env variables are only available inside modules (import.meta) and/or to be replaced in the production build with final string literals taken from env files. So the only way I can see to really expose a global variable is to write a plugin for the purpose or to explicitly pass it to globalThis somewhere in the app. Am I right? Or have I missed something that allows to have such a variable out-of-the-box?
